# Guidance on how to switch out default serializer in Lokad.Cloud

Tags: c#, autofac

http://code.google.com/p/lokad-cloud/wiki/Serialization

I have been trying to swap the default serialization in Lokad.Cloud.  I have tried something along the following:

```
public class ServiceWebModule : Module
{
    public string AzureConnectionString { get; set; }

    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Register(CloudStorageProviders).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }

    CloudStorageProviders CloudStorageProviders(IComponentContext c)
    {
        return CloudStorage
            .ForAzureConnectionString(AzureConnectionString)
            .WithDataSerializer(new SuperDuperJsonSerializer())
            .BuildStorageProviders();
    }
}
```

This module loads after the lokad cloud storage modules have loaded and I am attempting to override the runtime in Azure's implementation of CloudStorageProviders with my own.  Any guidance would help.  Thank you.

Comment: Without knowing how DI/Autofac is used in Lokad.Cloud: Try to remove the `PreserveExistingDefaults()` because as the name implies it will preserve the existing `CloudStorageProviders` registration so your custom one won't be resolved.

Comment: Oh sorry, I corrected my sample.  It was left over from me troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the lokad source `StorageModule`:

```
builder.Register(BlobStorageProvider);
builder.Register(QueueStorageProvider).OnRelease(queues => queues.AbandonAll());
builder.Register(TableStorageProvider);
builder.Register(CloudStorageProviders).OnRelease(storage => storage.QueueStorage.AbandonAll());
```

In addition to the `CloudStorageProviders` type being registered, each of the specific providers (`ITableStorageProvider`, `IBlobStorageProvider` and `IQueueStorageProvider`) are also registered. You will have to register all these explicitly in order to fully overwrite the existing registrations.

Comment: I haven't been able to figure it out yet but thanks for the detailed answer.  Cheers

Comment: @ElvisLives: have you tried registering all four providers? This is key, since only registering `CloudStorageProviders` (as you do in your sample) is not enough.